# How to keep homemade soup and cooking stocks/broths consumable without refrigerator?

Tags: food-preservation

Since there is a way for fruits, vegetables, meats, grains, seasonings and other stuff, I assumed there was a way for these flavouring liquids as well. Right now I'm wanting to preserve japanese dashi and korean kimchi but I think would be super nice to know of a method to preserve all types broths/stocks as well.

Comment: What about pasteurization and canning or bottling ?

Answer (score 3):

When laboratories need to grow bacteria in a dish, they use a medium which is basically broth with gelatin--the bacteria love it. Not even normal canning will sterilize broth enough to be safe. Broth must be pressure canned, and for a long time (75 minutes at pressure for pints, 90 minutes for quarts). Many soups can be canned this way as well, but be careful not to add dairy or thickeners of any kind--the liquid must be able to distribute the heat of the pressure canner evenly throughout the jar to ensure sterilization.

I preserve vegetable, chicken, and beef stock this way with good results. Dashi has a more delicate flavor that might not hold up to it, so probably the traditional method of dehydration is best.

Comment: So Lee, you use the machine described in the following site to preserve your broths and meat ?https://www.thespruceeats.com/pressure-canning-step-by-step-guide-1327465

Comment: I find hard to believe if so because old japanese didn't have said machine. Also, what do you mean with dehydrating dashi? Since it's mostly liquid I don't understand why this method of preservation is considered.

Comment: @DuarteAlfonsoMartin Back in the day they didn't have pressure canning machines, no. They also didn't fully understand bacteria and got sick a lot, and occasionally died.

Comment: That machine's a bit fancier than mine--I have a Presto pressure cooker/canner that you can find many places for less than $100, so it's not a big investment. Dashi itself is not dehydrated, but it is made from dehydrated components.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker So how would the dehydration occur of the dashi occur?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear... I'm saying that the traditional method of storing dehydrated Kombu, Bonito flakes, etc., is probably best. I've never tried to can or otherwise preserve Dashi after it's been made; I have no idea how well that would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make it acidic (sour) using lemon, vinegar, citric acid etc then it may be preserved with Sodium Benzoate. Do keep in mind the maximum permissible limits. It should not require canning or refrigeration.

Comment: Could you please add more information (and possibly a link or two) about how to use sodium benzoate? And I doubt the asker wants to change the soup’s flavor profile?